# Strange number conversion on live server?

Tags: asp.net

When I run my asp.net site in debug mode all is fine and dandy, for example numbers will be formatted like this: 0,21. 
But when I run my live site it becomes like this: 0.21. 
It's all crazy and I can't find anything in C# code that would do such a hideous thing. 
The theory I've if it's because of languages on the server or anything like that. 
What can be different from running locally in VS or running it live on IIS 6 on a
Windows Server 2003?

Comment: Looks like you have different localization settings on both machines. Please show codwe which output number to UI

Comment: Lots and lots of things could be different. Check the default culture/language on your server vs your workstation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tell-tale sign of default culture being other than expected.

Try adding the following to the `globalization` section of the `web.config` file and see if it helps:

German example:

```
<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-GB" />
```

See MSDN reference for implementation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx

Here are the cultures for different regions:
http://www.csharp-examples.net/culture-names/

Choose the one that may be right for you.

Comment: I think you have the OP's problem exactly backwards.